# What is the integral of $\log\left(x^{2} + k^{2}\right)$ ?.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Where $\displaystyle k$ is a real number ?. I have tried everything but I stuck when I have to find integral of
$k^{2}/\left(x^{2} + k^{2}\right)$.

Comment: You may try $x^2 + k^2 = (x - jk) (x + jk)$ ...

Comment: try the substitution $x = k\tan \theta$

Answer (score 2):

Integrate by parts.  $u=\ln(x^2+k^2)$ and $dv=dx$ to change to the integral

$$\int \frac{2x^2}{x^2+k^2} \; dx$$

which is do-able by ordinary methods.